# pandas time series average monthly volume

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have csv time series data of once per day date, and cumulative sale.  Silimar to this

```
01-01-2010 12:10:10      50.00
01-02-2010 12:10:10      80.00
01-03-2010 12:10:10      110.00
.
. for each dat of 2010
.
01-01-2011 12:10:10      2311.00
01-02-2011 12:10:10      2345.00
01-03-2011 12:10:10      2445.00
.
. for each dat of 2011
.

and so on.
```

I am looking to get the monthly sale (max - min) for each month in each year.   Therefore for past 5 years, I will have 5 Jan values (max - min), 5 Feb values (max - min) ... and so on

once I have those, I next get the (5 years avg) for Jan, 5 years avg for Feb .. and so on.

Right now, I do this by slicing the original df [year/month] and then do the averaging over the specific month of the year.

I am looking to use time series resample() approach, but I am currently stuck at telling PD to sample monthly (max - min) for each month in [past 10 years from today]. and then chain in a .mean()

Any advice on an efficient way to do this with resample() would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be best if you showed the code you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably look like something like this (note: no cumulative sale values). The key here is to perform a df.groupby() passing dt.year and dt.month.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.date_range(start='2016-01-01',end='2017-12-31'),
    'sale': np.random.randint(100,200, size = 365*2+1)
})

# Get month max, min and size (and as they are sorted - last and first)
dfg = df.groupby([df.date.dt.year,df.date.dt.month])['sale'].agg(['last','first','size'])

# Assign new cols (diff and avg) and drop max min size
dfg = dfg.assign(diff = dfg['last'] - dfg['first'])
dfg = dfg.assign(avg = dfg['diff'] / dfg['size']).drop(['last','first','size'], axis=1)

# Rename index cols
dfg.index = dfg.index.rename(['Year','Month'])

print(dfg.head(6))
```

Returns:

```
            diff       avg
Year Month                
2016 1       -56 -1.806452
     2       -17 -0.586207
     3        30  0.967742
     4        34  1.133333
     5        46  1.483871
     6         2  0.066667
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a `resample*2`:

- First resample to a month (`M`) and get the diff (`max()-min()`)
- Then resample to 5 years (`5AS`), and `groupby` month and take the `mean()`

E.g.:

```
In []:
date_range = pd.date_range(start='2008-01-01',end='2017-12-31')
df = pd.DataFrame({'sale': np.random.randint(100, 200, size=date_range.size)},
                  index=date_range)

In []:
df1 = df.resample('M').apply(lambda g: g.max()-g.min())
df1.resample('5AS').apply(lambda g: g.groupby(g.index.month).mean()).unstack()

Out[]:
            sale                                                                  
              1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10    11    12
2008-01-01  95.4  90.2  95.2  95.4  93.2  93.8  91.8  95.6  93.4  93.4  94.2  93.8
2013-01-01  93.2  96.4  92.8  96.4  92.6  93.0  93.2  92.6  91.2  93.2  91.8  92.2
```